# Unique Constraint for Set<String> with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having an Entity that contains a Set like the following:

```
@ElementCollection
Set<String> branches;
```

Now what Hibernate does, is creating a table `project_branches` (project_id | branches) and adding a unique constraint on `branches`. Is there any way to tell hibernate that the unique constraint should involve both, `project_id` **and** `branches`?

I could not find an answer to this question, though I think I'm not the first with this problem... Thanks

Comment: What? Could you show generated sql for `project_branches` table. And explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, I'm having an Entity "Repository". Now each repository has branches. But with the code above, Hibernate will not allow me to create Branch "master" for repository with id "1" and another Branch "master" for repository with id "2". But the only information I need about a Branch is its name, so I don't want to create a separate entity for it.
I hope that was more clear

Comment: So, do you want unique constraint or not? And if you do then where should it be?

Comment: Yes I do want a unique constraint on project_id **and** branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dependent on the columns involved in the mapping.

There in one other configuration. Please consider adding an `UniqueConstraint` annotation at entity level e.g. below:

```
  @Table(name="project_branches",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"project_id", "branches"})}
  )
```

**EDIT:** Try using `@CollectionTable` annotation.

```
 @ElementCollection
 @CollectionTable(
    name="project_branches",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="branches"),
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"project_id", "branches"})}
  )
  Set<String> branches;
```

Comment: Ok, you cannot add the `@Table` annotation to a property and as you can see, I don't want to create a new Entity for this, unless I really have to.

Comment: @entek: I didn't request to add at property level. I mentioned already as "consider adding an UniqueConstraint annotation at `entity level`"

Comment: Yes but because there is no Branch entity, there is not entity level. That's the problem.

Comment: `project_branches` table can be mapped as entity, NO?

Comment: My goal is to map this set of Strings without creating an Entity for it. Because it's really just a collection of Strings. The problem is just the unique constraint. I'd just like to know if it is possible to change that behavior.

Comment: How does hibernate create project_branches table? Can you please share the full mapping?

Comment: I posted the code in my question. This will cause Hibernate to create a table width the columns `project_id` and `branches` and put a unique constraint on the column `branches`.

Comment: Can you please check if `@CollectionTable` annotation help? I updated the asnwer with the same.

Comment: Wow we posted the same answer simultaneously :D
I will delete mine and accept yours. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution: Entity fields support the Annotation `@CollectionTable` so I was able to solve it like this:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "project_branches", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "project_id", "branches" }))
Set<String> branches = new HashSet<String>();
```